# Oledb Overflow error in ASP.NET 3.5 C# Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I am getting a strange "Overflow" error while inserting data to my access database. Actually it works fine locally, but not on the server so I think it can be an OS specific error as my local system is a 64-bit Windows 7 but cant say about the server. But even if it is an OS specific problem, it should have broke up with a numeric value being inserted but the data columns in my database are all text, memo and datetime and an auto-number field.

Here is the code:

```
string cmdd = @"Insert into Alumni_tb (A_Name, Batch, Stream, Adm_No, Email, Address,     Profession, Contact_No, Comments, Date_Added, Last_Update_Date, Active) 
values (@A_Name,@Batch, @Stream, @Adm_No, @Email, @Address, @Profession,@Contact_No, @Comments, @Date_Added, @Last_Update_Date , @isActive)";
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdd, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A_Name", aName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Batch", Batch);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adm_No", admno);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stream", stream);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", address);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Profession", prof);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact_No", contno);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comments", comments);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Added", dateAdded);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Update_Date", lastUpdateDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isActive", true);
            conn.Open();
            int cnt = 0;
            cnt=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (cnt > 0)
            {
                //Display Ok Message
                return;
            }
            else 
            {
                //Display Error Message
            }
```

The variable passing values to the params are all string and have been initalized and populated before defining the insert query.

In the database, the columns and datatype are described below.

```
A_Name is a Text;
Batch is Text;
Stream is Text;
Adm_No is Text;
Email is Text; 
Address is Memo;
Profession is Text;
Contact_no is Text;
Comments is Memo;
Date_added is DateTime;
Last_update_date is DateTime;
Active is Yes/No;
```

I only get an "Overflow" error message, at cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use SqlCommand..

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string cmdd = @"Insert into Alumni_tb (A_Name, Batch,     Stream, Adm_No, Email, Address,     Profession, Contact_No, Comments, Date_Added, Last_Update_Date, Active) values (@A_Name,@Batch, @Stream, @Adm_No, @Email, @Address, @Profession,@Contact_No, @Comments, @Date_Added, @Last_Update_Date , @isActive)
```

I did not see you used OleDbCommand, sorry..

Comment: First, I am using `OleDb` class and not `SQL`, so it should be `OleDbCommand` and second, even if it is `OleDbCommand` I think, it is exactly same as what I have done. There is almost no difference in both. Third, You have not included the Connection anywhere and that is a required parameter for initializing a new command.